# Ruby method chaining error

Tags: ruby, casting, ruby-2.0

The `TaxArray` class inherits from the `Array` class:

```
class TaxArray < Array

  # instance methods
  def for_region(region_code)
    self.select{|tax|tax[:region_code].include?(region_code)}
  end

  def for_type(type)
    self.select{|tax|tax[:type].include?(type)}
  end

end
```

It contains `hashes` of taxes:

```
@taxes=TaxArray.new
@taxes << {name: "Minnesota Sales", rate: 6.875/100, type: [:food,:liquor], region_code: 'MN'}
@taxes << {name: "Downtown Liquor", rate: 3.0/100, type: [:liquor], region_code: 'MN'}
@taxes << {name: "Downtown Restaurant", rate: 3.0/100, type: [:food], region_code: 'MN'}
# fictitious WI rates 
@taxes << {name: "Wisconsin Sales", rate: 5.0/100, type: [:food,:liquor], region_code: 'WI'}
@taxes << {name: "Wisconsin Food", rate: 2.0/100, type: [:food], region_code: 'WI'}
@taxes << {name: "Wisconsin Liquor", rate: 1.0/100, type: [:liquor], region_code: 'WI'}
```

The `for_type` method works as expected:

```
> @taxes.for_type(:liquor)
=> [{name: "Minnesota Sales", rate: 6.875/100, type: [:food,:liquor], region_code: 'MN'},{name: "Downtown Liquor", rate: 3.0/100, type: [:liquor], region_code: 'MN'},{name: "Wisconsin Sales", rate: 5.0/100, type: [:food,:liquor], region_code: 'WI'},{name: "Wisconsin Liquor", rate: 1.0/100, type: [:liquor], region_code: 'WI'}]
```

The `for_region` method works as expected:

```
> @taxes.for_region('WI')
=> [{:name=>"Wisconsin Sales", :rate=>0.06, :type=>[:food, :liquor], :region_code=>"WI"}, {:name=>"Wisconsin Food", :rate=>0.02, :type=>[:food], :region_code=>"WI"}, {:name=>"Wisconsin Liquor", :rate=>0.01, :type=>[:liquor], :region_code=>"WI"}]
```

However, when I chain the methods together, I get an error:

```
> @taxes.for_type(:liquor).for_region('WI')
NoMethodError: undefined method `for_region' for #<Array:0x007f90320d7c20>
```

Each method returns an `Array`, rather than a `TaxArray`.

Should I cast the returned value of each method to a `TaxArray` or is there another way?

Comment: you either need to override `select`, or just explicitly return new `TaxArray`s from your methods.  `select` by default returns a new array.

Comment: How would you cast it? In any case, if you want `select` to return a `TaxArray` then you need to return a `TaxArray`, otherwise it's just going to return an `Array`.

Comment: Note that `self.select` is the same as `select`, because if a receiver is not specified, `self` is the default (but `self` *is*  needed in `self.class` in @Zach's answer, to indicate the `class` keyword is not intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best solution but I would do it this way:

```
class TaxArray < Array

  ...

  def select
    self.class.new(super)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I wouldn't recommend subclassing Ruby primitives, for exactly the reasons you're bumping into.  It's just as simple to include an array instance variable and operate on that:

```
class TaxArray
  attr_reader :tax_hashes

  def initialize(tax_hashes)
    @tax_hashes = tax_hashes
  end

  def for_type(type)
    self.class.new(tax_hashes.select {|h| h[:type] == type })
  end
end
```

You could also just define your whole api in one fell swoop using `define_method`:

```
class TaxArray

  attr_reader :tax_hashes

  def initialize(hashes)
    @tax_hashes = hashes
  end

  [:name, :rate, :type, :region_code].each do |attr|
    define_method :"for_#{attr}" do |arg|
      self.class.new tax_hashes.select {|tax| Array(tax[attr]).include?(arg) }
    end
  end
end
```

And why not go one step further, and forward all unknown methods to the array, with the assumption that this class should respond to anything the array would:

```
class TaxArray
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if tax_hashes.respond_to?(name)
      self.class.new(tax_hashes.send(name, *args, &block))
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would define `select` anyway, even in this case. Why repeat cast in `for_region`?

Comment: I like the `missing_method` approach.  Is there a way to adapt it so that the `name` search uses a `regexp`?

Comment: @craig: yes! You can change the conditional statement (the line with `respond_to?`) to anything you wish. `name` is a symbol, but you can call `to_s` or use string interpolation ("#{name}") and apply your regex match.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your methods return plain array objects and it does not have the other method.

You can make your methods return a TaxArray object like so:

```
class TaxArray < Array
  def for_region(region_code)
    array = self.select{|tax|tax[:region_code].include?(region_code)}
    TaxArray.new(array)
  end

  def for_type(type)
    array = self.select{|tax|tax[:type].include?(type)}
    TaxArray.new(array)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem would be much simpler if instead of `TaxArray < Array` you implemented a simple `Tax` class like the following

```
class Tax

  attr_reader :name, :rate, :type, :region_code

  def initialize(name, rate, type, region_code)
    @name = name
    @rate = rate
    @type = type
    @region_code = region_code
  end

  def for_region(r_code)
    region_code.include?(r_code)
  end

  def for_type(t)
    type.include?(t)
  end
end
```

and performed the desired operations to a (usual) array of `Tax` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Module#refine](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-refine) for this (v2.1):

```
module M
  refine Array do
    def for_region(region_code)
      select { |tax|tax[:region_code].include?(region_code) }
    end

    def for_type(type)
      select { |tax|tax[:type].include?(type) }
    end
  end
end

using M

taxes = []
```

Now add some data (I've removed the hash element with key `:rate` to simplify slightly):

```
taxes << {name: "Minnesota Sales",    type: [:food,:liquor], region_code: 'MN'}
taxes << {name: "Downtown Liquor",    type: [:liquor],       region_code: 'MN'}
taxes << {name: "Downtown Restaurant",type: [:food],         region_code: 'MN'}
# fictitious WI rates 
taxes << {name: "Wisconsin Sales",    type: [:food,:liquor], region_code: 'WI'}
taxes << {name: "Wisconsin Food",     type: [:food],         region_code: 'WI'}
taxes << {name: "Wisconsin Liquor",   type: [:liquor],       region_code: 'WI'}

p taxes.for_type(:liquor)
  [{:name=>"Minnesota Sales",  :type=>[:food, :liquor], :region_code=>"MN"},
   {:name=>"Downtown Liquor",  :type=>[:liquor],        :region_code=>"MN"},
   {:name=>"Wisconsin Sales",  :type=>[:food, :liquor], :region_code=>"WI"},
   {:name=>"Wisconsin Liquor", :type=>[:liquor],        :region_code=>"WI"}]

p taxes.for_region('WI')
  [{:name=>"Wisconsin Sales",  :type=>[:food, :liquor], :region_code=>"WI"},
   {:name=>"Wisconsin Food",   :type=>[:food],          :region_code=>"WI"},
   {:name=>"Wisconsin Liquor", :type=>[:liquor],        :region_code=>"WI"}]

p taxes.for_type(:liquor).for_region('WI')
  [{:name=>"Wisconsin Sales",  :type=>[:food, :liquor], :region_code=>"WI"},
   {:name=>"Wisconsin Liquor", :type=>[:liquor],        :region_code=>"WI"}]
```

One of the restrictions in the use of `refine` is: ["You may only activate refinements at top-level..."](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which prevents evidently testing in Pry and IRB.

Alternatively, somewhere I read that this should work :-):

```
def for_region(taxes, region_code)
  taxes.select{|tax|tax[:region_code].include?(region_code)}
end

def for_type(taxes, type)
  taxes.select{|tax|tax[:type].include?(type)}
end

for_region(for_type(taxes, :liquor), 'WI')
```